# Activity Background based on weather image from flickr like Yahoo weather

Tags: android, flicker, weather, yahoo-weather-api

I want to show images from the current city based on weather as android app's background just like Yahoo! weather does.

Is there an API to get such images? I have been through Yahoo weather's developer resources and got to know that they don't provide any such feature.

### update

This is not duplicate of how to get 7 day or one day data, I am asking for how to get **Images** that are from local places and according to weather?

Comment: Minus ONE for What? Can you explain? I am not asking about getting weather data!

Comment: Bah, silly me! Apologies!

Answer (score 1):

Images on the Yahoo Weather app are aggregated from Flickr. Yahoo provides a Flickr API which you can plug into.

see https://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/